# assigning and grabbing a value to an element

Tags: jquery, textarea, element

I am trying to assign a value to my text area so I can compare it to the time of day and get different colors as time passes.  I understand the logic part just cant seem to grab a numeric value from my textarea element.
I have tried custom attribute as well as just value= but all I can seem to grab is undefined

HTML:

```
  <th class="col-1 hour 9">9 am</th>
                <th class=" col-10 events">
                    <textarea class="description" data-value="9"></textarea>
                </th>
                <th class="col-1 saveBtn"><i class="far fa-save"></i></th>
```

my attempt at jquery:

```
var event = $("*[data-value]")
for (let i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
    var timeArr = event[i];
    var timeEl = JSON.stringify(timeArr)
    console.log(timeEl.value)

}
```

Thank you for any help or tips you may have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($("*[data-value]"), function(index, element){
        console.log($(element).attr("data-value"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<th class="col-1 hour 9">9 am</th>
<th class=" col-10 events">
    <textarea class="description" data-value="9"></textarea>
</th>
<th class="col-1 saveBtn"><i class="far fa-save"></i></th>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It does not seem to be working though.
Don't I need a for loop to cycle through the different .descriptions?

Comment: I've just edited the answer. so the code will loop for every element with data-value attribute and print the corresponding value.